# How to localize radio-button inside admin interface in Kentico

Tags: localization, kentico

I have a custom Page Type with ArticleType field presented by Radio Buttons control with the following list of options:

News
Event

My website has EN and DE cultures. What I want to do is if content editor edits the page on German he sees:

Nachrichten
Veranstaltung

But if he switches to English, he would see:

News
Event

But the actual value saved in the database would be "news" or "event". How can I make it within Kentico admin interface?

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqFph.jpg)

Comment: You have to be more specific as to where this radio button is before anyone can help you with an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution proposed by Peter will display the same localization string even if you switch to another language in Pages application because it will use the culture of the user but not the culture of the page.

The following macro should work for you:

```
news;{% GetResourceString("custom.news", LocalizationContext.CurrentCulture.CultureCode) #%}
events;{% GetResourceString("custom.events", LocalizationContext.CurrentCulture.CultureCode) #%}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to do something simple like go to *localization*  and create resource strings in EN and DE for your radio buttons. Then you create a simple radio button set [image]